# Date values comparison Python list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, csv

I´m reding a csv file and I´m looking for create a function that makes comparations through items of the list. To be more clear, here is an example.

I convert the csv to list:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    lista = list(spamreader)
    print lista
```

`>>>[['"Fecha"', '"Cliente"', '"Subastas"', '"Impresiones_exchange"', '"Fill_rate"', '"Importe_a_pagar_a_medio"', '"ECPM_medio"'],['20/12/2017', 'Martin', '165.665', '3.777', '2,28%', '1,58', '0,42'], ['21/12/2017', 'Martin', '229.620', '18.508', '8,06%', '14,56', '0,79'], ['22/12/2017', 'Martin', '204.042', '48.526', '23,78%', '43,98', '0,91'], ['20/12/2017', 'Tom', '102.613', '20.223', '19,71%', '17,86', '0,88'], ['21/12/2017', 'Tom', '90.962', '19.186', '21,09%', '14,26', '0,74'], ['22/12/2017', 'Tom', '60.189', '12.654', '21,02%', '11,58', '0,92']]`

So, first, I need to comparate all values for Martin and for Tom. I mean, `item[2] of 20/12/2017 to item[2] of 21/12/2017. item[2] of 21/12/2017 to item[2] of 22/12/2017`. And I need these for all items of my list(item[2,3,4,5,6]. The date is the most important value because the idea is comparate one day with the other.

The results I hope are something like this:

```
21/12/2017 Martin 
item[2]: smaller
item[3]: smaller
item[4]: bigger
item[5]: smaller
item[6]: smaller

22/12/2017 Martin
item[2]: smaller
item[3]: bigger
item[4]: bigger
item[5]: bigger
item[6]: bigger

21/12/2017 Tom
item[2]: smaller
item[3]: bigger
item[4]: bigger
item[5]: bigger
item[6]: bigger

22/12/2017 Tom
item[2]: smaller
item[3]: smaller
item[4]: smaller
item[5]: smaller
item[6]: bigger
```

And if I want to show the names as "Subastas" instead of item[2] and all names too...how can I do it?

Comment: maybe use `pandas` module - it is more powerful.

Comment: use button `{}` to format list like you formated code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start by observing that you have lines of data for which the keys are `(date, name)`. One fairly obvious approach is to store the data in a dictionary that has `(date, name)` as the key.

So, taking your posted data in `mylist`,

```
mylist = [['"Fecha"', '"Cliente"', '"Subastas"', '"Impresiones_exchange"', '"Fill_rate"', '"Importe_a_pagar_a_medio"', '"ECPM_medio"'],['20/12/2017', 'Martin', '165.665', '3.777', '2,28%', '1,58', '0,42'], ['21/12/2017', 'Martin', '229.620', '18.508', '8,06%', '14,56', '0,79'], ['22/12/2017', 'Martin', '204.042', '48.526', '23,78%', '43,98', '0,91'], ['20/12/2017', 'Tom', '102.613', '20.223', '19,71%', '17,86', '0,88'], ['21/12/2017', 'Tom', '90.962', '19.186', '21,09%', '14,26', '0,74'], ['22/12/2017', 'Tom', '60.189', '12.654', '21,02%', '11,58', '0,92']]
```

convert it (except for the first row with the column labels) to a dictionary like this:

```
import datetime
mydict = {}
for row in mylist[1:]:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],'%d/%m/%Y')
    name = row[1]
    mydict[(date,name)] = row[2:]
```

The tricky bit here is that your dates are strings of the form `dd/mm/yyyy` but you will later want to do a comparison between one day and the next. This will be no surprise because you put this issue as the topic of your question. So you need to convert the string date into something you can do proper comparisons with. That is what `strptime()` does.

Your data now looks like this:

```
>>> mydict
{(datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 20, 0, 0), 'Martin'): ['165.665', '3.777', '2,28%', '1,58', '0,42'],
 (datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 22, 0, 0), 'Tom'): ['60.189', '12.654', '21,02%', '11,58', '0,92'],
 (datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 21, 0, 0), 'Martin'): ['229.620', '18.508', '8,06%', '14,56', '0,79'], 
 (datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 21, 0, 0), 'Tom'): ['90.962', '19.186', '21,09%', '14,26', '0,74'],
 (datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 20, 0, 0), 'Tom'): ['102.613', '20.223', '19,71%', '17,86', '0,88'],
 (datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 22, 0, 0), 'Martin'): ['204.042', '48.526', '23,78%', '43,98', '0,91']}
```

The next thing to observe is that your data consists of floating point numbers and percentages, but represented as strings. This makes things complicated because you want to do comparisons. Take the first 2 data points for Martin:

```
    ['165.665', '3.777', ...
    ['229.620', '18.508', ...
```

If you compare `'165.665'` with `'229.620'` the first one will be smaller, which is what you expect. But if you compare `'3.777'` with `'18.508'`, the first one will be bigger: not what you expect. That is because strings are compared alphabetically and `3` comes after `1` in an alpha sort.

To make matters worse, your data represents the decimal point sometimes as a comma and sometimes not.

So you will need a function to do a numeric conversion of the strings. Here is a naive one that works for your data but would probably need to be made more robust in real life:

```
def convert(n):
    n = n.replace(",",".").replace("%","")
    try:
        return float(n)
    except ValueError:
        return 0e0
```

Now you are in a position to do the comparison:

```
for (day, name) in mydict:
    previous_day = day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    if (previous_day,name) in mydict:
        print datetime.datetime.strftime(day,"%d/%m/%Y"), name
        day2_values = mydict[(day, name)]
        day1_values = mydict[(previous_day, name)]
        comparer = zip(day2_values, day1_values)
        for n,value in enumerate(comparer):
            print "item[%d]:" % (n+2,),
            if convert(value[1]) < convert(value[0]):
                print value[1], "smaller than", value[0]
            else:
                print value[1], "bigger than", value[0]
        print
```

I have made the messages more explicit, for example, `item[2]: 165.665 smaller than 229.620`. This is so that you can easily verify that the program is correct without having to dig back into the data, which is error-prone and tedious. You can always make the messages less explicit later if you want.

```
22/12/2017 Tom
item[2]: 90.962 bigger than 60.189
item[3]: 19.186 bigger than 12.654
item[4]: 21,09% bigger than 21,02%
item[5]: 14,26 bigger than 11,58
item[6]: 0,74 smaller than 0,92

21/12/2017 Martin
item[2]: 165.665 smaller than 229.620
item[3]: 3.777 smaller than 18.508
item[4]: 2,28% smaller than 8,06%
item[5]: 1,58 smaller than 14,56
item[6]: 0,42 smaller than 0,79

21/12/2017 Tom
item[2]: 102.613 bigger than 90.962
item[3]: 20.223 bigger than 19.186
item[4]: 19,71% smaller than 21,09%
item[5]: 17,86 bigger than 14,26
item[6]: 0,88 bigger than 0,74

22/12/2017 Martin
item[2]: 229.620 bigger than 204.042
item[3]: 18.508 smaller than 48.526
item[4]: 8,06% smaller than 23,78%
item[5]: 14,56 smaller than 43,98
item[6]: 0,79 smaller than 0,91
```

To show `"Subastas"` instead of `item[2]`, recall that the column labels are in the first element of `mylist`:

```
>>> mylist[0]
['"Fecha"', '"Cliente"', '"Subastas"', '"Impresiones_exchange"', '"Fill_rate"', '"Importe_a_pagar_a_medio"', '"ECPM_medio"']
```

So to include them in the output, you need to change this line:

```
print "item[%d]:" % (n+2,),
```

to

```
print mylist[0][n+2] + ":",
```

Comment: For effort +1   _

Comment: if I want to show the names as "Subastas" instaed of item[2] and all names too...how can I do it?

Comment: I need help with my question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48001004/data-csv-dashboard-python. It is very similar as this! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can load lista into a dataframe and then perform the comparison from there:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

headers = lista.pop(0)

df = pd.DataFrame(lista, columns = headers)

martin = df[df['"Cliente"'] == 'Martin']
tom = df[df['"Cliente"'] == 'Tom']

merge = pd.merge(martin, tom, on = '"Fecha"')

stats = headers[2:]
compare = ['"Fecha"']

for index, row in merge.iterrows():
    for x in stats:
        merge[x+'_compare'] = np.where(row[x+'_x'] > row[x+'_y'], 'Martin', 'Tom')
        if x+'_compare' not in compare:
            compare.append(x+'_compare')

print(merge[compare])

#output
"Fecha" "Subastas"_compare  "Impresiones_exchange"_compare  "Fill_rate"_compare "Importe_a_pagar_a_medio"_compare   "ECPM_medio"_compare
20/12/2017  Tom Martin  Martin  Martin  Tom
21/12/2017  Tom Martin  Martin  Martin  Tom
22/12/2017  Tom Martin  Martin  Martin  Tom
```