# Data CSV Dashboard python

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

With help from this foro I can create my Optimizator dashboard. Now, I need to make some changes. This is the code:

```
import csv
import datetime

with open("prueba.csv", 'rb') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    your_list = list(reader)



mydict = {}
for row in your_list[1:]:
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(row[0],'%d/%m/%Y')
    name = row[1]
    mydict[(date,name)] = row[2:]


def convert(n):
    n = n.replace(",",".").replace("%","")
    try:
        return float(n)
    except ValueError:
        return 0e0


for (day, name) in mydict:
    previous_day = day - datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    if (previous_day,name) in mydict:
        print name, datetime.datetime.strftime(day,"%d/%m/%Y")
        day2_values = mydict[(day, name)]
        day1_values = mydict[(previous_day, name)]
        comparer = zip(day2_values, day1_values)
        for n,value in enumerate(comparer):
            print "item[%d]:" % (n+2,),
            if convert(value[1]) < convert(value[0]):
                print value[1], "smaller than", value[0], "Incremento"
            else:
                print value[1], "bigger than", value[0], "Descenso"
        print

>>>
Martin 18/12/2017
item[2]: 312341 smaller than 349805 Incremento
item[3]: 45368 smaller than 46818 Incremento
item[4]: 14.53% bigger than 13.38% Bajada
item[5]: 39.35 bigger than 32.98 Bajada
item[6]: 0.87 bigger than 0.70 Bajada

Jose 11 03/12/2017
item[2]: 140580 smaller than 161540 Incremento
item[3]: 4943 bigger than 4663 Bajada
item[4]: 3.52% bigger than 2.89% Bajada
item[5]: 2.04 bigger than 1.95 Bajada
item[6]: 0.41 smaller than 0.42 Incremento

Jorge cl 17/12/2017
item[2]: 156736 smaller than 164272 Incremento
item[3]: 39295 bigger than 36921 Bajada
item[4]: 25.07% bigger than 22.48% Bajada
item[5]: 19.74 bigger than 19.61 Bajada
item[6]: 0.50 smaller than 0.53 Incremento
```

I need to change the returns `items[2],items[3],items[4],items[5] and items[6]` for the real names : `[['"Fecha"', '"Cliente"', '"Subastas"', '"Impresiones_exchange"', '"Fill_rate"', '"Importe_a_pagar_a_medio"', '"ECPM_medio"']`

Also, I need to save the returns in a csv file order by Cliente name. Is it possible??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real names are in `your_list[0]`. So change this line

```
print "item[%d]:" % (n+2,),
```

to this:

```
print your_list[0][n+2] + ":",
```

To save the output as a `csv`, instead of (or as well as) printing your data out, you need to save it so that you can pass it to `csv.writer`. Create a list called `result`, and for every row that you want to see in the output, do

```
row = [name, datetime.datetime.strftime(day,"%d/%m/%Y"), mylist[0][n+2],value[1], value[0]]
result.append(row)
```

After you have finished building `result`, sort it on name:

```
result.sort()
```

Use `csv.writer()` to produce your `csv` file from this list, one call to the writer object's `writerow()` method for every row in `result`.

Comment: Hey bro, I edited your answer to change something. Please, can you edit the code I copied there and make it real? Thanks

Comment: Please, check this. I creat a txt file with all information about the code and what changes I need! https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Nt63Zk3euTK2Ar4AGWpfsgbsCBAoH4cu/view?usp=sharing